Find 18 Month Gaps in Invoice Data with SQL
I need help with this SQL query. I have this table that includes every Invoice since 7/1/2020. The table has CustomerID and InvoiceDt in it. For every CustomerID I need to know if there is an 18 month gap in transactions, and if there was I need the date of the first transaction after the most recent 18 month gap
This is what the table that I am using as my input looks like (I refer to it as m in my code)



CustomerID
InvoiceDt




1
'2020-1-2'


1
'2024-1-2'


1
'2024-2-2'


2
'2020-12-1'


2
'2021-12-1'


2
'2022-12-1'


2
'2023-12-1'


2
'2024-2-1'


3
'2024-2-12'



This is the result that I want. Customer 1 has an 18 month gap between their 1st and 2nd purchase so I want the date of the second purchase. Customer 2 has no gap so I dont want them included in the result. The Data goes back to 7/1/2020 so there is at least 18 months of gap at the beginning for Customer 3 so I want their first invoice date. I refer to this table as startDates in my code



CustomerID
Modified Start Date




1
'2024-1-2'


3
'2024-2-12'



I was able to do this with no problem in Python, but I cannot wrap my head around doing it just within a groupby without using a loop in SQL
for cid in m.CustomerID.unique():
  m1 = m[m.CustomerID== cid]
  m1["InvShift"] = m1.InvoiceDt.shift(1)
  m1["Gap"] = ((m1.InvoiceDt - m1.InvShift)/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')/30.42)
  m1["18MonthGap"] = m1.Gap >= 18
  if m1["18MonthGap"].sum() > 0:
    startDates.ModStartDate.loc[cid] = m1[m1["18MonthGap"]].drop_duplicates("18MonthGap", keep="last").iloc[0].InvoiceDt
  elif m1.iloc[0].InvoiceDt > pd.to_datetime("2022-1-1"):
    startDates.ModStartDate.loc[cid] = m1.iloc[0].InvoiceDt


please have a look on LAG/LEAD-fucntions

I hope your InvoiceDt values are stored as proper date types and not as strings.  If a customer has more that one 18-month gap, do you want the after-gap invoice for all such cases?

You use the lag() windowing function, which hopefully is available in your environment.
select customer_id,invoice_dt
from
    (select customer_id,invoice_dt
     ,lag(invoice_dt) over (partition by customer_id order by invoice_dt) prev_dt
    from invoices
    )
where months_between(invoice_dt,prev_dt) > 18

If you don't have months_between you should still have some function that will allow you to compute the interval between two dates. I hope your dates really are dates,and not strings, as they look like they might be.
So far as your requirement for Customer 3. That is probably most easily done using a UNION to the query above:
select customer_id,first_invoice
from
    (Select customer_id,min(invoice_dt) first_invoice
    from invoices
    group by customer_id
    )
where first_invoice > date'2022-01-01'


The question was tagged as SQL Server, but you are using the months_between() function and date'...' syntax that appears to be Oracle. In SQL Server, the DATEDIFF(month, ...) function can be used, and date literals do not use the date prefix.
Also, as an alternative to the UNION (or UNION ALL), the ISNULL() function can be used to provide the default initial date for when LAG() returns no value. The following should handle all cases: where DATEDIFF(month, invoice_dt, ISNULL(prev_dt, '2022-01-01')) > 18.

Yes, hadn't noticed the sql-server tag

Correction to the above - swap the date values in the DATEDIFF() to get a positive difference. fiddle.

Never mind, I think this worked. The lag function was producing negative values so I just had to change the last line. WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, InvoiceDt, PrevDt) < -18

@Highflyer999 - Or swap the values and use: WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, PrevDt, InvoiceDt) > 18. Note that this compares boundaries and ignores day-of-month, so DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2024-03-31, 2024-04-01) and DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2024-03-01, 2024-04-30) both equal 1. An alternative is to test for InvoiceDt > DATEADD(month, 18, PrevDt), which does recognize days.

You can use the LAG() window function to access the prior invoice date. If no prior value exists for the customer, your starting data can be injected using the ISNULL() function.
You can then add 18 months and compare with the current invoice data to check the gap.
-- All 18-month gaps
SELECT CustomerID, InvoiceDt
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        LAG(InvoiceDt) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY InvoiceDt) PriorInvoiceDt
    FROM Invoice
) IP
WHERE DATEADD(month, 18, ISNULL(PriorInvoiceDt, '2020-07-01')) <= InvoiceDt
ORDER BY CustomerID, InvoiceDt

If you only want the latest after-gap date, you can GROUP BY CustomerID and select the MAX(InvoiceDt).
-- Latest 18-month gap, using GROUP BY and MAX() to get latest per customer
SELECT CustomerID, MAX(InvoiceDt) AS InvoiceDt
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        LAG(InvoiceDt) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY InvoiceDt) PriorInvoiceDt
    FROM Invoice
) IP
WHERE DATEADD(month, 18, ISNULL(PriorInvoiceDt, '2020-07-01')) <= InvoiceDt
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerID

However, if you want to include other information from the Invoice row (not shown in the sample data) or the prior date in the results, you can instead use the ROW_NUMBER() window function to assign descending row numbers and then filter for the latest.
-- Latest 18-month gap, using ROW_NUMBER() to get latest per customer
-- This allows access to the entire invoice row, not just the date.
SELECT CustomerID, InvoiceDt, PriorInvoiceDt
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY InvoiceDt DESC) AS RN
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            LAG(InvoiceDt) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY InvoiceDt) PriorInvoiceDt
        FROM Invoice I
    ) IP
    WHERE DATEADD(month, 18, ISNULL(PriorInvoiceDt, '2020-07-01')) <= InvoiceDt
) IPN
WHERE IPN.RN = 1
ORDER BY CustomerID

Finally, if you prefer to avoid multiple nested selects, you can refactor the query to use CTEs (Common Table Expressions).
-- Same as the above, but using CTEs instead of subqueries
;WITH InvoiceAndPriorDate AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        LAG(InvoiceDt) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY InvoiceDt) PriorInvoiceDt
    FROM Invoice I
),
InvoiceAndPriorDateNumbered AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY InvoiceDt DESC) AS RN
    FROM InvoiceAndPriorDate IP
    WHERE DATEADD(month, 18, ISNULL(PriorInvoiceDt, '2020-07-01')) <= InvoiceDt
)
SELECT CustomerID, InvoiceDt, PriorInvoiceDt
FROM InvoiceAndPriorDateNumbered IPN
WHERE IPN.RN = 1
ORDER BY CustomerID

Results (with some extra test data):



CustomerID
InvoiceDt
PriorInvoiceDt




1
2024-01-02
2020-01-02


3
2024-02-12
null


4
2024-01-01
2022-01-01


5
2023-09-01
2022-02-28


7
2022-07-15
2021-01-15



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
